# edit actionbar's title when button clicked

Tags: android

how could I edit my actionBar's title when I click on a button

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("dummy title"); // this is working

button.setOnClickListener(v->{
            Log.d("TAG", "click"); // this is working
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title); // not working
            setTitle(title); // not working
            mToolbar.setTitle(title); // not working
        });
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be great

Comment: try this ActivityName.this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

Comment: no it's not working, I'm just trying to load data from an API and then update the actionbar's title